# Laravel 5 UnexpectedValueException in response of query due to use of POINT data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I wanted to add a POINT field for latitude and longitude in my project and I found this [tutorial](http://www.codetutorial.io/geo-spatial-mysql-laravel-5/) that I mimicked to make sure it was working, but I'm stuck on why this error is occurring now:

```
UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 403:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Which if I back out the POINT field changes doesn't occur and I get the JSON data that allows me to use a Google Maps Geocoding of the address instead of the latitude and longitude data.

The endpoint action looks like this, which only works without the POINT data:

```
public function rentals($id)
{
    // Retrieve all rentals within a region and the locations spatial data
    $rentals = DB::table('rentals')
                 ->join('regions', 'rentals.region_id', '=', 'regions.id')
                 ->join('rental_locations', 'rentals.rental_location_id', '=', 'rental_locations.id')
                 ->where('rentals.region_id', '=', $id)
                 ->select('*')
                 ->get();

    // Create a collection from the array of query results
    $rentals = collect($rentals);

    // Group all rentals by location
    $rentals = $rentals->groupBy('rental_location_id');

    $data = [ 'rentals' => $rentals ];

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

The accessor and mutator are essentially the same from the tutorial, but I changed the location field name to latitude_longitude:

```
public function setLatitudeLongitudeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes[ 'latitude_longitude' ] = DB::raw("POINT($value)");
}

public function getLatitudeLongitudeAttribute($value)
{
    $location = substr($value, 6);
    $location = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ',', $location, 1);

    return substr($location, 0, -1);
}
```

Migration for Rental Locations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('rental_locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('street_address', 100);
        $table->string('city', 50);
        $table->string('province', 50);
        $table->string('country', 50);
        $table->string('postal_code', 10);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Laravel's schema creation doesn't support geographic data - July 2015 Laravel version 5.1
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE rental_locations ADD latitude_longitude POINT');
}
```

Seed for Rental Locations

```
protected $rentalLocations = [
    [
        'street_address' => '707 Johnson St.',
        'postal_code' => 'V8W 1M8',
        'latitude_longitude' => '48.4271731,-123.3644049'
    ],
    ...
];

public function run()
{
    // Rentals situated within available regions used during development
    foreach ($this->rentalLocations as $rentalLocation) {

        // Rental locations used during development
        factory(App\RentalLocation::class, 1)->create($rentalLocation);
    }
}
```

Factory for Rental Locations

```
$factory->define(Parkable\RentalLocation::class, function ($faker) {

    return [
        'street_address' => '',
        'city' => 'Victoria',
        'province' => 'British Columbia',
        'country' => 'Canada',
        'postal_code' => '',
        'latitude_longitude' => ''
    ];
});
```

and I made latitude_longitude fillable in the RentalLocation Model.

I tried adding all the parameters to the response as suggested on [Laracasts forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-problem-with-utf-8-in-a-json-response) in case it was a UTF-8 issue, but that didn't change anything:

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: what is at line 403 in Response.php add to your question please... the function that returns preferably :D

Comment: @mtpultz have you came up with the solution for this? I am also stuck on this. When I add table which has point spatial key to join, i will get this error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Sadee, I wasn't able to solve this issue.  I ended up just using Google Maps Geocoding instead of lat and long.  It was super frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I think I should ask more questions before I post this answer, but I think you're doing things in the wrong order.

```
public function rentals($id)
{
    // Retrieve all rentals within a region and the locations spatial data
    $rentals = DB::table('rentals')
                 ->join('regions', 'rentals.region_id', '=', 'regions.id')
                 ->join('rental_locations', 'rentals.rental_location_id', '=', 'rental_locations.id')
                 ->select('*')
                 ->where('rentals.region_id', '=', $id)
                 ->groupBy('rental_location_id')
                 ->get();


    return collect($rentals); // or return $rentals
/* Not necessary
    // Create a collection from the array of query results
    $rentals = collect($rentals);


    // Laravel is set up to return collections as json when directly returned
    return $rentals;
*/
}
```

So you need to add your groupBy in the query itself because that is a query action that your SQL should be doing. The other part is that when you convert it to a collection (which isn't 100% necessary) you can just return it. Laravel handles the JSON natively.

Comment: @mtpultz I checked the tutorial so I don't know which part of this you're attempting to use the point exactly or how that has anything to do with it, but what I'm giving should work let me know!!

Comment: Hi, that appears to throw the same error.  I took the implementation as is except for the field name change, and didn't use the scopeDistance action.  Basically I wanted to use POINT data, and have the mutator and accessor handle the formatting.  So I pass in lat and long as 'lat,long' and it converts to POINT and vice versa.  If I back out just that field that I'm trying to add everything works.

Comment: can you tell me more about which part is returning the error? we are 100% that the rentals function is returning the boolean?

Comment: also can you verify what version of mysql you're using?

Comment: Using MySQL 5.6.19 which comes with Homestead 2.  I make a single RESTful call out to my RentalController@rentals to get all the rentals in a region, as well as that rentals location data.  Prior to adding this tutorial into my model this was returning the right information and I had to use Google's geocoder to get the position via the address information passed back, but I wanted to instead use latitude and longitude as POINT data as I can make a Google maps marker without using the geocoder.  Now the exact same action returns this error.

Comment: It's the error being thrown in Laravel's Response object if the $content isn't a string, number, or an array that can be converted to a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83359/discussion-between-cayce-k-and-mtpultz).

Comment: @mtpultz so.. I just ran in this today... I'm not sure why I'm getting a true return on my query, but I am now. So can get the json from a `dd($array)` or I just pass it to a view and use it. I am still not sure why this is happening though. Wish I could have figured it out.. so weird.