# Laravel 5 UnexpectedValueException on response

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and for some reason I'm getting this error from time to time:

> UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 397:
>   The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

What is very frustrating is this is very unpredicted and it only happens from time to time - so it's very difficult to even debug since it's not consistent. I've got a simple route to just dump out a translation file, as follows:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    return trans('restaurant');
});
```

If I keep refreshing the page, it shows the output fine most of the time. However, once every 20-30 calls, I get the error! Can someone shed some light here please?

here is the stack trace:

```
UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 397:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
in Response.php line 397
at Response->setContent(false) in Response.php line 54
at Response->setContent(array(...)) in Response.php line 200
at Response->__construct(array(...)) in Router.php line 1229
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), array(...)) in Router.php line 709
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in LocaleSettings.php line 30
at LocaleSettings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LocaleSettings), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter.php line 53
at LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in LocaleSessionRedirect.php line 25
at LocaleSessionRedirect->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LocaleSessionRedirect), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 49
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: What is normally the value of `trans('restaurant');` when you don't get the error?

Comment: It's an array, but Laravel normally converts the array to JSON when spitting out.

Comment: its already answer, kindly please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436047/laravel-5-unexpectedvalueexception-in-response-of-query-due-to-use-of-point-data

Comment: *if it is possible* attempt to `json_encode(trans('restaurant'))` and the result is good or not. What I mean is if the content you expect is actually possibly to have it as string value or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just add exception handler. So that you can handle what data to appear when an error occurred.

```
Route::get('test', function() {
        $response = trans('restaurant')
        try{
          return $response;
        } 
        catch(Exception $e) {
           return [];
        }
    });
```